# Change automatically from "Ready to Produce" to "Done" in the mrp module of Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Just as you can use schedules for changing a manufacturing order status, from "Awaiting Raw Materials" to "Ready to Produce", I would like to know if there is a way to automate the process so it jumps directly to "Done", assuming that the products has all its Raw Materials of course. I'm using Odoo 9 for a restaurant, so there is no point to wait for a confirmation to produce the dishes

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your attempt so far. This website is about helping people with specific problems.Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved already I created an automation action and used the mrp model